Why is VS code hiding several lines of code and how do I turn it off?
VS Code upgraded itself, and now it's hiding several lines of code inside of a collapsed horizontal area. What is this feature called and how do I turn it off?
E.g.

I want to see lines 6 through 10 but VS Code is hiding them from me.

When you scroll, do both screens scroll at the same time? It could be splitting the display so you can view two parts of the code at once?

It's called "Stick scroll."  Turn it off in the settings.
